# Android FCM: Call API in the background when app receives notification

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible if an app (foreground/background/killed) receives a push notification (need to have a message to display), it can call an API in the background without the need of the user to tap on the notification and open the app?

Comment: No! there is no technique you can call api when notification is occur and app in background.

Comment: But you can see some other api available and do like [this](https://onesignal.com/)